# Drag&Drop to DataGrid item control (get current item index)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I have datagrid template and some textbox control into each row at datagrid.
So, how to drag and drop into textbox on row?

I know how and what i should drop, but i do not know how to get the position of datagrid item that i should drop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out if you're over a particular `DataGridRow` in the `PreviewDragOver` event handler:

```
private void PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult hitTestResult = 
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(sender, e.GetPosition(sender));
    DataGridRow dataGridRowUnderMouse = 
        GetParentOfType<DataGridRow>(hitTestResult.VisualHit);
    // Do something with dataGridRowUnderMouse 
}

private T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (element == null) return null;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (parent == null && ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent is DependencyObject) 
        parent = ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent;
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent.GetType() == type || parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type)) 
        return parent as T;
    return GetParentOfType<T>(parent);
}
```